# Why is my array returning undefined after post request?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a function that adds a detail into an array of details and a second function that makes the post request to the server. The first time i run addDetail() and then addOrder() the console.log() inside addDetail() shows an array. But the second time that i want to run both functions without reloading the page, the console.log() inside addDetail() returns undefined.

In clearOrder() at the end of addOrder() i set the array to empty: this.order.details=[];

```
async addDetail() {
  let leave = 0;
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `product/products/${this.detailProduct}`
    );
    const product = response.data.product;

    const data = {
      product: product.name,
      quantity: this.detailQuantity,
      aggregateDiscount: this.detailAggregateDiscount,
      price: parseFloat(
        (
          product.finalPrice * this.detailQuantity -
          (product.finalPrice *
            this.detailQuantity *
            this.detailAggregateDiscount) /
            100
        ).toFixed(2)
      )
    };
    this.order.total += data.price;
    let num = parseFloat(this.order.total.toFixed(2));
    this.order.total = num;
    this.order.details.push(data);
    **console.log(this.order.details);** // returns undefined the second time
    this.detailProduct = "";
    this.detailQuantity = 1;
    this.detailAggregateDiscount = 0;
  } catch (err) {
    errorAlertHandler(err, "No encontrado");
  }
},


async addOrder() {
    const data = {
      number: this.totalOrders + 1,
      description: this.order.description,
      customer: this.order.customer,
      deliveryDate: this.order.deliveryDate,
      details: this.order.details,
      total: this.order.total,
      deposit: this.order.deposit,
      status: this.order.status
    };
    try {
      await axios.post(`/order/add`, data);
      this.dialog = false;
      this.dialog2 = false;
      this.getOrders();
      this.clearOrder();
      this.$store.dispatch("showAlert", {
        status: true,
        type: "success",
        text: "Pedido creado"
      });
    } catch (err) {
      errorAlertHandler(err, "No encontrado");
    }
},
```

Comment: It would be a good start to have all functions in your question because you may have changed the array in those functions and we will never know if its not in your question

Comment: All functions are included in the question.